# Would a VPN allow me to get around the monthly data cap set by my ISP?

Tags: vpn, bandwidth, bandwidth-control, bandwidth-measuring

My total data allowed without being charged extra is 50gb during 8am-12am and unlimited overnight from 12am-8am. I have to watch how much HD streaming I do and mass downloading because of this. Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Yes it helps... configure the VPN to ignore every request of you during 8am-12am, and make it only accept traffic during overnight.

Comment: On a serious side, no, just taking a VPN won't magically make you consume less bandwith. Video/audio are pretty compressed already which takes away the benefit from compressed channels. If possible, download your files in the night with a scheduled task or cron.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Lekensteyn, I usually do my downloading at night with a scheduler unless I want or need it right away. I wanted to check around before I paid for a VPN. I appreciate the feedback and sorry for being off topic for serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this won't help.  Your ISP will still see the traffic going to the VPN end point.  They are just counting bytes and don't care where your packets are going or what they are doing.

Answer (score 2):

No.
A VPN will not magically produce less traffic (well maybe a little bit less if you compress the traffic).
You will still use the bandwith, just not directly to the destination anymore but to your VPN provider first.